# mysql dump in java not working

Tags: java, mysql

i am trying this command in java

```
executeCmd = DBConfig.dbLocation + "\\mysqldump -u " + mysqlUser +
    " -p"+DBConfig.dbPass + " " + DBConfig.dbName + 
    " -r -opt>supervisorDbBkup.sql";
```

Its giving me code 1  instead of 0

```
            String executeCmd = "";
    executeCmd = DBConfig.dbLocation+"\\mysqldump -u"+mysqlUser+
            " -p"+DBConfig.dbPass+" "+DBConfig.dbName+" -r -opt>supervisorDbBkup.sql";

    Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
    int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
    if(processComplete == 0){
        return "Backup taken successfully";
    } else {
        return "Could not take mysql backup";
    }
```

this is the command which i am running :

```
                E:\program file\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump -uroot -p0502 dashboardsupervisor -r -opt>supervisorDbBkup.sql
```

any idea

Comment: Which OS do you use? Show use how you'll execute `executeCmd`.

Comment: win7 , i have pasted the code above

Comment: Does DBConfig.dbLocation point to MYSQL_HOME/bin ?

Comment: yes , its   :   public static String dbLocation ="E:\\program file\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin";

Comment: this is the command which i am running :    E:\program file\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump -uroot -p0502 dashboardsupervisor -r -opt>supervisorDbBkup.sql

Comment: program file? or program files?

Comment: file , its in program file , location is correct , i can open it in my pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to print out the contents of `executeCmd` after you've built it, to see what it contains, with something like:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine (executeCmd);
```

If that command doesn't work at the command line exactly as you've constructed it, it's unlikely to work within your program. Copy and paste the command *exactly* as it's output and attempt to execute it from a `cmd` shell.

I suspect your problem lies with the path to the executable or one of the options.

If that's not the case, you need to watch out for redirection. Redirection is a *shell* feature which may not be available to the `Runtime.exec()` call. What you will find is that the redirection bit is being passed as a parameter to the `mysqldump` execuatble which won't understand it at all.

The usual way to do this is to call the shell itself with arguments telling it how to run the command and redirect properly, something like:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "/path/to/mysqldump blah blah >/tmp/tempout"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

(or equivalent `cmd /c` for Windows).

That ensures that redirection is handled correctly (by the shell itself) and the `mysqldump` executable only gets the arguments it understands.

Comment: if i run the same command in shell , it works fine .. it creates a new file in the bin folder ,  in java i am expecting it to save the new file in the war folder..

Comment: thats what i am getting :  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "E:/program file/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/bin/sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: its working with this code :  String executeCmd = “”;
executeCmd = “mysqldump -u “+dbUser+” -p”+dbPass+” “+dbName+” -r backup.sql”;

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
executeCmd = "<Absolute Path to MYSQL>\bin" + "\\mysqldump -u " + mysqlUser +
    " -p"+DBConfig.dbPass + " " + DBConfig.dbName + 
    " -r --opt > supervisorDbBkup.sql";
```

**UPDATE:**

-opt is not an option for mysqldump following is

```
--opt
```

Comment: will there be a single \ before bin ??

Comment: Print the output of runtimeProcess using runtimeProcess.getInputStream(); to better understand the exception

Answer (score 0):

try with this command
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqldump -u username -pPASS_WORD database_name -r backup.sql"

Mind the space between -u and username and -p and password(there should be no space between -p and password).
It worked for me.